# python. переменные в символак как

Tags: python, переменные

смотрите я хочу задать что / = print
чтобы облегчить себе жизнь, и делать так:
/("lol")
как сделать чтобы питон не выдавал ошибки и код работал:

> ```
> / = print
> /("lol")
> ```

Comment: Никак не сдалть. Потому что ``/`` это а) не литера, б) вообще знак деления.

Answer (score 3):

Можешь облегчить себе жизнь, взяв какую-нибудь букву, а не символ, который вообще нельзя использовать в именах.

```
p = print
p(3)
```